# Upgrade Tensorflow 1.x code to Tensorflow 2.x code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to update a TF1 code to TF2 code on google colab, using the following command that I found on the tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade#compatibility_modules) and also on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmSNUeBG-PQ):

!tf_upgrade_v2 -h --infile medgan.py --outfile medgan_upgraded.py

But seems like it's doing nothing. It's showing no error, just shows how to implement the syntax which I'm already following. The instruction in the youtube video is pretty straightforword but I have no idea why this is not working. Can anyone help me with some ideas about what I might be missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-h` parameter is for getting *help* on the command.

Try executing it without it, as:
`!tf_upgrade_v2 --infile medgan.py --outfile medgan_upgraded.py`

Comment: Thank you for your help. it's working. I actually started this way but it was not working because of the environment I guess but I fixed that.